# An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rubygems

I have Rails 4.2.5 and ruby 2.0.0 installed.

This is a Gemfile of a project :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "whenever"

gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'

gem 'geokit'

gem 'sequenced'

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'

gem 'bcrypt', :require => 'bcrypt'

gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

# Paperclip
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"

gem "thin"

gem "passenger"

gem 'geocoder'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

When I make bundle install I receive the following error : 
   "An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling."

And if I make gem install eventmachine I have the following error

```
make "DESTDIR=" compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:
./project.h:116:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
Gem files will remain installed in        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/ext/gem_make.out
```

How Can I fix it?

Comment: You have to install openssl on your operating system before you install eventmachine. BTW, according to my experience, eventmachine does not work well with rails 4.2. You will have to downgrade to rails 4.1

Comment: I already tried installing openssl but it did not work. Any other advice?

Comment: If you are using El Capitan, you would have to use sudo when installing OpenSSL.

Comment: @pauloancheta Yes, I did it

Comment: Try brew link openssl --force

Comment: @Aetherus EventMachine working bad with rails 4.2 should not be true, since it is a dependency of `ActionCable` which is a feature available from rails 5 (but also available for Rails 4.2.3+)

Comment: @Kkulikovskis active_record 4.2 does not have the class `ClosedTransaction`, which em-synchrony depends on.

Comment: @Aetherus not really true either: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ClosedTransaction   this is for Rails 4.1.7.

Comment: @Kkulikovskis Yes there is the class in rails up to 4.1.15, but not in rails 4.2.

Comment: I agree with @Kkulikovskis

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this problem before and running the command below worked

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'  -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

I can't remember where I found it or the reason why this work. Maybe someone else can complement the answer.

Comment: Had similar problem, but mine says `-v '1.0.7'`; replaced the 3 with 7 and it worked! I Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks..this solution worked for 1.0.7

Comment: Thanks man! it worked for `-v 1.0.7`

Comment: Installing  ruby-dev  solved the issue for me.

Comment: for me it was because I did not have `g++` installed, I guess `ruby-dev` is also necessary then